# What is the engineering term for the gear style articulated arm

Tags: structural-engineering

[image: "gear style component" - unknown name]

You loosen a screw (knob) and then move to the angle you want and tighten.

I need to know what the engineering term for this part is.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Bolted joint. I have lamp with a boom arm that can be adjusted with loosening a bolt at its joint.

Comment: I think he's asking specifically about the "gear style", or toothed component?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a 'universally recognised' name for this. "Toothed Clamping Element/Plate" was the most common that I could find, with multiple sellers online using this terminology.

[image: Toothed Clamping Element][image: Clamping Element Diagram]

These are often used in conjunction with spring-loaded clamping lever/screws, which allow you to disengage the lever by pressing down on the screw head.

[image: Clamping Lever]

Comment: For @Sadie - the teeth, are just called “teeth” as far as I can tell...